# C# MVC - combine 2 models into 1 model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently learning MVC in C#, and faced with below problems.

I have 2 models created already, and both work fine.

Model 1:

```
 public class MeetingResolutionViewModel
{
    public string ResolutionNo { get; set; }
    public string ResolutionCd { get; set; }
    public string ResolutionDesc { get; set; }
    public long EventId{ get; set; }
}
```

Model 1 is mapped like this:

```
public static void MapToMeetingResolution(IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg)
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<PxVotingResolution, MeetingResolutionViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ResolutionId, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ReverseMap();

        cfg.CreateMap<PxVotingElection, MeetingResolutionViewModel>()
            .ReverseMap();
    }
```

Model 2:

```
public class ProxyVotingViewModel
{
    public bool RoleUpdate { get; set; }
    public bool RoleElect { get; set; }
    public long EventId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Model 2 is mapped like this:

```
public static void MapToProxyMeeting(IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg)
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<EventDetail, ProxyVotingViewModel>();
    }
```

Model 1 and Model 2 share the same EventId column.

I am creating another view model like below. It is a combination of above 2 models with the "MeetingResolutionViewModel" model in a list.

```
public class ProxyVotingEmailViewModel
{
    public List<MeetingResolutionViewModel> MeetingResolutionViewModel { get; set; }
    public ProxyVotingViewModel ProxyVotingViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Using auto mapper, I have done the mapping as following:

```
public static void MapToProxyVotingEmailViewModel(IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg)
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<ProxyVotingViewModel, ProxyVotingEmailViewModel>();

        cfg.CreateMap<MeetingResolutionViewModel, ProxyVotingEmailViewModel>();
    }
```

In my function below, how can I solve the 2 problems mentioned in the comment?

```
public async Task<CommandResult<List<string>>> SendEmail(List<MeetingResolutionViewModel> data)
{
//blah blah

                var emailData = new ProxyVotingEmailViewModel();
                var pxData = new ProxyVotingViewModel();

                /* I would like to do 2 things:
                 * 1) get pxData using the EventId from data[0];
                 * 2) get emailData value by combining pxData with data (as per the view model definition)
                **/

                //blah blah
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the purpose of auto mapper. It allows you to map values from one object to another. `ProxyVotingViewModel` does not map to `ProxyVotingEmailViewModel` its just a property. So you would just assign it, no need for mapping.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try direct assignment then.